# How to test validity of es6 imports before commit

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, githooks, git-commit

I have a react/redux based large codebase comprising of the following hierarchy:

Routes >> Container >> Components

which means that Routes contain Containers and Containers contain Components.

I'm using a lot of es6 import across my code - to import stuff if each other and also to import svg's and npm packages like lodash.

If I refactor the path of the import:

```
import x from '../../path1';
```

to

```
import x from '../shorterPath2';
```

How can I run some tests across my codebase to ensure that for all files - the imports are correctly resolved - that all filepaths from which things are being imported will return an asset or something from a index.js present there:

Should I

1. write my own nodeJS script/ shell script
2. try something from javascript testing framework - can this be done??
3. will git-hooks work here??

Please give me a direction to think on and I can code the rest.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a testing framework if I were you ([Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started.html) or [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) should work). A broken import will cause your program to crash, which will, in turn, cause your test to fail. Just make sure that your test ends up importing every file in the project. As for forcing those tests to run on on commits, I'd look into [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky)